# Help to set up RAID on a DELL Poweredge 400SC

Tags: windows, raid

I have a FastTrak S150 TX2 raid controller that I have downloaded the driver for. I am installing WinXP fresh but don't have a floppy disk. Is there another way to load these drivers on boot?

Anyone? Anyone at all...

Answer (score 1):

With any windows OS before Vista  (and server 2008) you have to use a floppy drive to add raid (or other hard disk) drivers through the F6 page of the windows installation.

You can use a USB Floppy if your bios will support it,
Also if you want to take the time to manually build your own windows install disk, you can slipstream the drivers into it.  Just google 'slipstream hard disk drivers windows' for some help there.

Comment: Actually your USB floppy drive must be supported by 1° the BIOS 2° the windows CD boot subsystem 3° the core windows system itself. It's often extraordinarily painful to get it working (you may have to hack some .ini files in the CD image).